# Why is my program returning NameError: name 'self' is not defined as the error

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a program to tell me how many posts I've liked using the InstagramAPI module. It's returning `NameError: name 'self' is not defined` and I'm not sure why.

This is my code:

```
from InstagramAPI import InstagramAPI
import time, json, re
import json
import requests
import os
username = ''
password = ''

i = InstagramAPI(username, password)

i.login()

def getTotalLikedMedia(self, scan_rate=1):
        next_id = ''
        liked_items = []
        for x in range(0, scan_rate):
            temp = self.getLikedMedia(next_id)
            temp = self.LastJson
            try:
                next_id = temp["next_max_id"]
                for item in temp["items"]:
                    liked_items.append(item)
            except KeyError as e:
                break
        return liked_items

getTotalLikedMedia
```

Comment: Maybe it is a Class,

Comment: You should call your function and assign to it arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` represents the instance of the `class`. By using the argument bound to the name `self` we can access the attributes and methods of the `class`.

You appear to be defining a method without the class it is supposed to be a method of.

```
class something:
   def __init__(self, something):
      self.something = something

ins = something()
```

Comment: ``self`` is just a name.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA It's a special name.

Comment: @mR-Jacaj No, it's not special in any means, it is just a convention to name first arguments to methods `self` in Python.

Comment: @fisheye So you should not use it, it may confuse people. That's why I said it's a special name.

Answer (score 0):

Without posting entire traceback it is impossible to know what really happened. I guess that the code you posted is not how it really looks like on your computer. It seems like a method definition but here it is just a plain function, where `self` is just an argument called... well, self. Technically nothing is wrong with that, and calling that method would probably result in raising `AttributeError`, when the interpreter tries to execute line `temp = self.getLikedMedia(next_id)`, unless you passed as `self` some object that does have the method `getLikedMedia()`.